# Azure application gateway v2

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-gateway, azure-waf

Could you please help me?
I currently work with Azure application gateway waf v2 and when I try to access an application it redirects me perfectly but it does not take the variables

for example when I try to access https://toto.app.com/Event?hash=xxxxx&key=xxx this redirects me to the web app but does not take the hash and key into account, whereas if I access without an application gateway with xxxazurewebsites... it does take the hash and key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check this [MsDocs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/rewrite-http-headers-url) to understand  the Rewrite HTTP headers and URL with Application Gateway.

If you want key values to pair with parameters, you can use query string for ex: it you want `https://www.contoso.com/design/xyz` to `https://www.contoso.com/buy.xyz`you can use condition in server variable

[image]

Make use query string value and URL path value accordingly.

[image]

And check this supported list of [variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/rewrite-http-headers-url#server-variables) in azure application gateway

To know more in detail, refer this link.

[Rewrite HTTP request and response headers in portal - Azure Application Gateway | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/rewrite-http-headers-portal)